# Dropdownlist in ASP.NET causes page refresh only on first Index Change

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently have a dropdownlist located inside of an Updatepanel. I have an event handler setup for the selection change event. PartialPageRendering is set to true in the script manager. The first time I select an item in the dropdownlist the whole page is reloaded. After that it only triggers the event like it should. I am capturing the PagePostBack event in the code, but the first time the index changes, this does not get set, after that it works as expected. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div style="text-align:center">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"   OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged" Font-Size = "48">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                        <br /> 
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>

                </Triggers> 
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
```

Comment: Don't you need to add the control into the `<Triggers>` section?

Comment: I haven't reproduced the problem with the markup shown above. You can include in the question any part of the code (client or server) that modifies the content or the behavior of `DropDown1` or the update of the page.

Comment: The control I'm using is the DropDownList, which is included in the Updatepanel. I didn't think this needed to be a trigger, since it is already in the UpdatePanel, and works fine after the first change. The only modification I am doing to DropDown1 is in the Page_init, where I populate the list with names.